# Subset data.frame based on a list

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, subset

Sample Data : https://www.dropbox.com/s/f3l2uub1cttwmf2/test.csv?dl=0

I need to subset this data.frame based on only those county codes (fips) that are available on another dataset.  I have a list of all the fips codes from the other dataset and am trying to remove all those not in the list, but am not having much luck.

From this small sample dataset are three fips (8009,8011,8013), so how would i remove all except for 8009 and 8011 in the context that this would be a list.

Here's what I've tried :

`prism.dd <- prism.d[(prism.d$fips %in% fips) ,]`

Where fips is a list of 779 fips to keep:

`fips <- unique(DustBowlData_Pre$fips)`

But it's only returning the same number.  A solution with data.table would be preferred, but what works best is also fine.

Thanks!

Edit : Update for akrun's request :

Output of dput(head(fips))

`c(8009L, 8011L, 8013L, 8017L, 8035L, 8039L)`

Update : str(prism.d)

```
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  52802 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ fips: int  30061 30063 30077 30049 30013 30059 30045 30027 30069 30033 ...
 $ Year: int  1910 1910 1910 1910 1910 1910 1910 1910 1910 1910 ...
 $ ppt : num  87 64.2 52.4 46.6 34.9 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Solution :

```
setkey(setDT(prism.d), fips)
fips <- unique(DustBowlData_Pre$fips)
fips <- data.table(fips)
Subpr <- prism.d[fips]
```

Thanks @akrun!  This worked perfectly.  I really need to learn data.table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(prism.d), fips)
fips <- c(8009, 8011)
fips1 <- data.table(fips)
Subpr <- prism.d[fips1]
```

#### Update

I think the previous code didn't work because I thought the dataset is `data.frame` and not `data.table`. Try

```
fips2 <- fips #renaming because `prism.d` has the `same` column name `fips`
prism.d[fips %in% fips2]
```

#### data

```
 prism.d <- read.csv('test-1.csv')
```

Comment: thanks for this, but the issue is I have a large list of fips codes (779) that I need to subset.  So while your answer works for this example, it doesn't work for the large dataset I have because I would need to list out all 779 fips codes

Comment: In a list.  See above.  I've stored the fips code into $fips with unique()

Comment: I changed it to `prism.dd <- prism.d[(prism.d$fips %in% unlist(fips)) ,]` but it's still returning the same number of obs without subsetting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66177/discussion-between-amstell-and-akrun).

Comment: also, I don't think the ! is appropriate here as I'm trying to specifically subset certain fips codes

Comment: I wanted to subset based on what was in the fips list

Comment: That worked....however, this doesn't seem to pull the fips codes from the other database and apply it to the prism database....the DustBowlDat_Pre has all the fips codes I need, but this doesn't appear to use that....

Comment: @Amstell I am sorry, it is not clear what the objective was.  I thought you wanted to subset the `prism.d` based on `fips`